# Changing <a> link underline color

Tags: css, cross-browser

I wonder if there is any trick to solve this problem.

I have my link as below text and want to change the underline color.

**This link contains in many lines which needs to change the underline color to be lighter than the existing one**

Using border bottom is not the way to solve this because multiple lines.

are there any trick to solve this?

***EDIT***

@Paolo Bergantino: **It works with IE8 , is it possible to hack with IE6,7?**

Comment: It doesn't work for me on IE7 either, actually. That's odd.

Comment: ah, I test wrong windows, only works on IE8

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to come up with anything.

Comment: That's ok, I have try it too but not yet find anything yet.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: In 2021 you can use text-decoration-color https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996777/3335517

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If what you mean is a different underline color than what the text is, the only thing I can think of is to add a span around the link:

```
<span class='underline'>
    <a href="#">this just<br>a test<br>of underline color</a>
</span>
```

And then the CSS:

```
span.underline { 
    color: red; 
    text-decoration: underline; 
} 
span.underline a { 
    color: blue; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

And [you get what you want](http://jsbin.com/uzuju).

**EDIT**:

Testing this a little further, it is not working for me on IE. If you add border-bottom, however, it surprisingly does work in all browsers, except that IE does not put a border under the last one. I will try to dig a little deeper to see if there's a cross-browser way to do this...

Comment: This example could be even cooler if every major browser supported the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-selector.

Comment: That's going to affect all link selectors, so a user won't be able to distinguish what link they have visited.

Comment: I shall be making a note of this for future reference, its so simple yet works perfectly.

Answer (score 18):

In case anyone is interested - this worked for me - text-decoration-color CSS property:

```
.example { 
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color

2121 update: this works great! Other useful CSS is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset for controlling the distance between the underline and the text.

Comment: The ideal solution, but its still not supported by chrome :(

Comment: This is the property to use for modern browsers.

Comment: As of today all major browsers support this property.

Comment: This is the one.

Answer (score 15):

Paolo Bergantino's answer didn't seem to work for me in Chrome on OSX (v19.0.1084.56). However moving the span inside of the a tag seemed to do the trick.

The HTML

```
<a class="underline" href="#">
    <span>Hello world<br>this is a test<br>of changing the underline colour</span>
</a>​
```

And the CSS

```
.underline {
    color: red;           
}

.underline span {
    color: gray;           
}
```

You can view it here: http://jsfiddle.net/itsmappleby/f4mak/

Comment: Works on FF, IE6-10, Chrome, Safari.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use border. This method work at ie6.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class='underline'>
  <span>this just</span><br/>
  <span>a test</span><br/>
  <span>of underline color</span>
</a>
```

CSS

```
  a.underline {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  a.underline span {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 12px;
  }
```

and example: http://jsfiddle.net/skanY/1/embedded/result/

Comment: -1 the downside of this is you have to pay closer attention to the content of the <a> tag. If the text is wrapping within a box, rather than you inserting breaks this isn't going to work.

Comment: actually, you can replace "inline-block" to "inline", and this works, but not correctly

Comment: If you could explain that in your answer I can remove my downvote! Apparently I can't until the answer is edited. In what way does it not work correctly though?

Comment: You can remove "inline-block" like this http://jsfiddle.net/skanY/4/. Then if the text is wrapping within a box, underline correctly show, but lower than in shold be.

Answer (score 2):

Underlined, being a text attribute, inherits the text's color. So I doubt there is a way to explicitly change the underline color without also changing the text color.

Answer (score 2):

The Underlining of  links will always be the same color as the text.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for ressing an old question, but i was having the same issue, and didn't find a satisfying answer, so i came up with a different solution and thought i'd share it with you.

it does include a 1x1 background image (or whatever size you prefer), but it's clean and simple - and 100% browser compatible (tested from IE6 and up).

this example has text that changes color, and the underline stays the same. you can just as easily do it other way around.

```
a, a:link, a:active, a:visited{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#888;
    background:transparent url('underline.png');
    background-position:0 10px;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

a:hover{
    color:#009ee0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I'd add this...

```
a:active, a:link, a:visited{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0)50%, #ff5400 50%);
    text-decoration: none;
    background-size: 2px 2px;
    background-position: 0 1.2em;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Note: Older browser support is not completely supported

Answer (score 1):

USE:

```
<a href="your-link/" style="text-decoration-color: COLOROFUNDERLINE;">
```

Answer (score 0):

the underline on links is done using the text-decoration css style, i think it's the same color as the text.

if you set the text-decoration to none then add a border-bottom you can change the color with the border-color style.

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use this code to make underlines with different color. Use the Borders

```
h1{
     border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA
}
```

edit:
you can use java script to draw a line under the text

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your answer doesn't seem helpful here: the OP said specifically that "Using border bottom is not the way to solve this because multiple lines."