# Underlining an html anchor with different color

Tags: html, css, anchor

Is it possible to underline an anchor tag with a color other than its text color? Any example will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Is it possible to specify color as hex e.g. #8f867c ?

Comment: The person who voted to close: can you please comment why?

Comment: Don't worry it's a valid question. I also don't know why somebody voted to close this.

Comment: Check this working link : [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/5s9UZ/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing <a> link underline color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175383/changing-a-link-underline-color)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot specify the underline color separately, but you can use a little trick:

```css
a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

Note that the border will not appear *exactly* where the underline would have appeared, sorry.

Comment: But be aware that if you create an anchor around an image, the image will get the dotted underline as well. This can become very annoying.

Comment: Is it possible to give color as hex? e.g #8f867c

Answer (score 5):

CSS3 allows you to use `text-decoration-color: #8f867c` to set the color directly.

```css
p {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #8f867c;
}

span {
  color: #8f867c;
}
```

```html
<p>My underline is <span>#8f867c</span></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want the "border" to only show when user moves his mouse over it you should do something like this:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: The second `text-decoration` (the `:hover` one) is redundant.

Comment: Not necessarily. He could have defined a "hover" state somewhere else that would have "text-decoration: underline" in-it.

Answer (score 2):

It's better you can give **border** to it. write like this:

```
a{
text-decoration: none;
color:green;
border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/dgc4q/

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to underline an anchor tag with a color other than its
>   text color? Any example will be appreciated.

I find that weird, but I just learned: [Yes, it is](https://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/vpXOwG), if you wrap a span inside.

**html:**

```
<a href='#'><span>Howdy Partner</span></a>
```

**css (sass)**

```
html
  font-size: 6em

a
  color: red

span  
  color: green
```

[image]

**little advantage over `border-bottom`-solution:**

You are certainly not affecting base-line, line-height, margin collapse, spacing between lines... (depending on situtation, border-bottom could do that)