# jQuery plugin for changing underline color?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there any plugin, that changes the link underline color and text color remains?
I need to add that functionality to existing HTML code and haven't found something good yet.
I can't change HTML so I can't wrap `<a>` or `<span>` and CSS this.

Comment: You could change the html with jQuery to wrap the element

Comment: Underline decoration is a part of text and cannot be colored separately

Comment: I hope this link help's you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175383/changing-a-link-underline-color

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just remove the underline by setting text-decoration to none, then adding a border-bottom:1px red solid or what ever you want with JS on hover?

This sounds like 2 lines of jQuery, or 3-10 lines of JS.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/acukit) | [source](http://jsbin.com/acukit/edit):

```
$("selector for the links you want to change").css({
  "text-decoration": "none",
  "border-bottom": "1px solid green"
});
```

Comment: This is a +1 without the sarcasm. Stack Overflow is *specifically intended* for people to come here and ask questions, even basic ones.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't meant to be snarky, I was on my iPod, and intended to come back and add the code. I was trying to say that changing the underline is impossible, but a border-bottom is OK, and that it is a quick job. I assumed they didn't know you use border-bottom, rather than that they didn't know JS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to change a link, right? Can you not change the html or do you just not have access to it? If you can change it, I'd suggest something like this:

```
//set the anchor color to the underline
$('a').css('color', '#fff');

//get the text in the link and wrap it in a span with the text color
var linkText = $('a').innerHTML();
var linkText = '<span style="color:#000">' + linkText + '</span>';

//update the anchor with the new html
$('a').innerHTML(linkText);
```

Let me know if that makes sense :)